How to Enable Multi-Unit Booking Logic in WP Rentals Theme?
In my WP Rentals theme, I have properties listed in a similar way to Airbnb. Some listings are entire apartments, while others are individual rooms within those apartments.
Here's the issue:

Booking an Entire Apartment: When the entire apartment is booked, the individual rooms within it should automatically be marked as unavailable.
Booking an Individual Room: If one room within an apartment is booked, the entire apartment should be marked as unavailable since it’s no longer fully available.

Currently, the WP Rentals theme doesn't offer an automatic way to handle these booking dependencies.
What I've tried so far:
I’ve been manually marking the entire apartment as booked whenever a room is reserved. This is not a sustainable solution for me.
What I need:

An automated solution that ensures when an entire apartment is booked, all individual rooms are marked as unavailable.
An automated solution that ensures when a room is booked, the whole apartment is made unavailable.

I manage six apartments and their respective rooms on my WordPress site, so having this functionality is critical for efficient management.
How can I achieve this within the WP Rentals theme? Are there any plugins, code snippets, or settings that could help?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
